# compare date in SQL c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, date

I have problem in my code when i want to get data that for specific date !
My sql statement:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select a.acc_id,a.acc_Name,a.acc_Place,b.type,
b.acc_sub_debt,b.acc_sub_payment,
b.acc_sub_returned,b.acc_sub_date,COALESCE(b.acc_sub_note,' ') from accounts a, 
account_Details b where a.acc_ID = b.acc_Sub_ID 
where b.acc_sub_date = '" + DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Text).ToShortDateString()
 + "' order by b.id desc", objConn);
```

The Error is:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntac check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'where b.acc_sub_date = '14/2/2015' order by b.id desc' at line
>   1"

Comment: You have "where" twice. Did you mean "where .... and ..." ?

Comment: This will be crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn i bet you can't resist the temptation.

Comment: Also, the TableA,TableB join syntax is so last century.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
string sql = 
 @"select a.acc_id,a.acc_Name,a.acc_Place,b.type,b.acc_sub_debt,b.acc_sub_payment,b.acc_sub_returned,b.acc_sub_date,COALESCE(b.acc_sub_note,' ') 
   from accounts a, account_Details b 
   where a.acc_ID = b.acc_Sub_ID and b.acc_sub_date = @subDate 
   order by b.id desc";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, objConn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@subDate", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Text);
```